# Adding integer boundaries to list input? Python3

Tags: list, python-3.x, integer

I'm creating a colours database. For this database, I want to the user to be able to add their own colour if they may. Originally, I had done this using a list.append. I would have the user to add a colour by the user putting in the shade colour, and its RGB values. This data would then be passed to a function where I would add it to the database. I'm now trying to change this by ensuring the RGB values are between 0 and 255. If the figure is not between 0 and 255, it should print out that the value is incorrect, and they must add a new figure. This is what I have so far:

```
def addColour():
    values = []
    values.append (input("What shade is the colour?\n"))
    red = values.append(int(input("What is its red value?\n")))
    while red > 255 or red < 0:
        print("That is an incorrect figure. It must be between 255 and 0")
    values.append(input("What is its green value?\n"))
    values.append(input("What is its blue value?\n"))
    insertData(values)
```

I then add the input from the user into the database with: (just for reference)

```
def insertData(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("colours.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "insert into Colours (Shade, Red, Green, Blue) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()
        question = input("Do you want to add another colour?")
        if question.lower() == "y":
            addColour()
        else:
            mainMenu()
```

The type error I get is also listed below:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: `list.append` returns `None`. Also, you've got an infinite loop there, if your code actually gets into it.

Comment: How would I go about implementing an integer boundary on what the user can input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about implementing an integer boundary on what the user can input?

In a loop, assign the input value to a variable instead of putting it straight into your list. Check it's in the right range. If it is, end the loop. Otherwise, print a message and allow the loop to restart.

When the loop's done, and you have an acceptable value, *then* you put it in your list.

E.g.

```
while True:
    red = int(input('What is its red value?'))
    if 0<=red<=255:
        break
    print('The value must be between 0 and 255.')
values.append(red)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, have a nice day!